# Limit videojs to div height

Tags: html, css, html5-video, video.js

I am trying to use a `div` container to limit the size of a `video-js` video. I want to define the limit by **height** but `<div style="height:50%>"` has no effect, `width=50%`, however, works fine.

This is the entire `test.html` that I'm testing in Chrome.

```
<head>
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.3.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<div style="height:50%">
    <video class="video-js" controls loop muted preload="none" data-setup='{ "fluid": true, "playbackRates": [0.2, 0.25, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 0.85, 1.0] }'>
        <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</div>

<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.3.0/video.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try with height of `600px` and `overflow: hidden`

Comment: @roottraveller In the `div` style, or the `video`?

Comment: `<div style="width: 100%; height: 600px; overflow: hidden;">` adjust px of height as needed if this worked.

Comment: @roottraveller That still resulted in it being stretched to the full width of the screen, just all the controls are chopped off with the bottom of the video.